# extra newlines when pasting altered string in visual block mode

Tags: visual-block

Suppose I have an open buffer containing the following text

```
1111111111
1        1
1 222222 1
1 2    2 1
1 2 33 2 1
1 2 33 2 1
1 2 33 2 1
1 2    2 1
1 222222 1
1        1
1111111111
```

I can visually select and yank the 2-rectangle with the command `3gg2l<Ctrl-V>8jey`

Then, I can immediately reselect and paste the yanked text (not changing the
buffer) with `gvp`.

However, it seems like as soon as I write to the `@@` or `@"` register (even if
I don't change the value), something changes, and pasting doesn't work right
anymore.

For example, doing

```
:let @@=@@
:normal! gvp
```

changes the buffer to

```
1111111111
1        1
1 222222
2    2
2 33 2
2 33 2
2 33 2
2    2
222222 1
1  1
1  1
1  1
1  1
1  1
1  1
1        1
1111111111
```

inserting the contents of the register as new lines, rather than overlaying the
visual selection.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: I faced the same problem, but I worded my question in different words and got a different answer. http://vi.stackexchange.com/questions/7593/how-to-paste-a-text-block-in-visual-block-mode

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem comes from the register type, you can use `echo getregtype('"')` before and after your `let @@=@@` and you'll see that the type has changed.

[`:h getregtype()`](http://vimhelp.appspot.com/eval.txt.html#getregtype%28%29) tells us that a register can have different types:

> "v"           for characterwise text
>
> "V"           for linewise text
>
> "{width}" for blockwise-visual text
>
> ""            for an empty or unknown register

So when you select your rectangle with <kbd>ctrl+v</kbd> and then you yank it, you actually set the type of the `"` register to visual block (Here `^V6` actually)

When you do `let @@=@@` you do no respect the register type. Thus you do not past in block wise mode anymore.

The correct way to set a register is to use the function `setreg()` which accepts as parameter the register type to set. See [`:h setreg()`](http://vimhelp.appspot.com/eval.txt.html#setreg%28%29)